# Discord Bot not responding after first command

Tags: javascript, arrays, bots, discord, discord.js

So I am having some issues with creating my bot. All I am trying to have it do, is keep track of a list of players that type the command "+me" to join a "waiting list", "-me" in order to be removed from the list, and "?list" in order to display the list. I plan to add other commands later.

The issue I am having, is that the command works fine to add someone to the list, however after the first command the bot stops responding to commands. This leaves me able to add myself to the queue, but then not able to leave, no one else able to join, not able to list it, etc.
Also if you could mention a way to move the for loop I am using to display the list into a seperate function I would greatly appreaciate it. I am new to Javascript and my attempts are crashing it for some reason.

[image: Exmaple of issue]

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const {prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
var rankedList = []; // Initialise an empty array

client.login(token);

client.once('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Ready!');
})

client.once('message', message =>{
    // Add to queue
    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}me`)){
        console.log(message.author + "added to queue.");
        message.channel.send(message.author + " added to queue.");

        var temp = message.author;
        rankedList.push(temp);  // the array will dynamically grow

        // Show queue after adding
        //for (var i = 0; i < rankedList.length; i++) {
        //  message.channel.send(i+1 + "- " + rankedList[i]);
        //}
        message.channel.send(`${rankedList.map((player,index) => `${index+1} - ${player}`).join('n')}`);
    }

    // Remove from queue
    if(message.content.startsWith(`-me`)){
        console.log(message.author + "removed from queue.");
        message.channel.send(message.author + " removed from queue.");

        for( var i = 0; i < rankedList.length; i++){ 
            if ( rankedList[i] === message.author) {
                rankedList.splice(i, 1); 
                i--;
            }
        }

        // Show queue after removing
        for (var i = 0; i < rankedList.length; i++) {
            message.channel.send(i+1 + "- " + rankedList[i]);
        }
    }

    if(message.content.startsWith(`?list`)){
        console.log(message.author + "displayed the queue.");

        // Show list
        for (var i = 0; i < rankedList.length; i++) {
            message.channel.send(i+1 + "- " + rankedList[i]);
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Does your console return any error? Anyway, it’s really not suggested to have so many event functions for one even. Move all your `client.once(‘message, (m)=>{}’)`’s under one function. It’s not suggested to edit the `i` variable inside a `for(let i = ...)`. Before going over to large discord bots, get used with JavaScript. Code cleanup would be really wished here.

Comment: I have moved the functions inside one message block! Also it returns no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be you have used "once" instead of "on". The latter triggers event every time, while the former listens once.

```
// Add to queue
client.on('message', async (message) => {

   // It's good practice to ignore other bots. This also makes your bot ignore itself and not get into a spam loop
    if(message.author.bot) return;

    if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}me`)){
        var temp = message.author;
        rankedList.push(temp);  // the array will dynamically grow
        console.log(message.author + "added to queue.");
        message.channel.send(`${message.author} added to queue.
        ${rankedList.map((player,index) => `${index+1} - ${player}`).join('
n')}`);
    }
});
```

You are basically sending the entire message at once. I could see that the send() function is asynchronous [ https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/DMChannel?scrollTo=send ]and should not be chained in a for loop like above. The above code is also more concise

I have used template literals [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals ] to remove multiple concatenation.

Comment: I got the same result

Comment: can you try adding the `async` keyword before the function ?

Comment: also try using 'on' instead of 'once'

Comment: since if you are using once, it does not listen to the events again, probably, which was the issue to begin with!!